# So Weird...TestFlight has two same build package processing

Tags: ios, xcode7, testflight

I am submitting a new app version to TestFlight, using Xcode or Application Loader. But I meet a wired problem, I have two same build number package, and one is processing over 24 hours, the other has completed long time ago.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

[Cann't Select the newest package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaMwF.jpg)

[Two same build processing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EzHu.jpg)

Comment: Until now, the problem has answered by apple iTunes customer service representative. He said, iTunes will hold the build package data for about 30 days, out of that, the old build package will be deleted automatically.
And if the problem I met happened, they can't delete the wrong build package manually.Here is a walk-around way to solve this problem.
Changing the version forwardly will be acceptable on iTunes, then choose the new version to TestFlight test. If passed, build a new package using the old version, then choose this package to submit to itunes to waiting for approval.
Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just re submit a new build with a higher build number and it should sort itself out and allow you to then select the newest build.

Comment: I have submit 3 newer build. But the Build 4021 still processing, I can NOT select newer build...

Comment: So weird, Apple or TestFlight bug?! what a surprise

Comment: Finally, I email the apple and get a telephone feedback. They help me delete the duplicated build. after that, every thing goes well.